# Opera can't load GWT application hosted on cyrillic domain

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, dns

Application loads without any troubles with other browsers. But in Opera if we access application by it cyrillic domain name the app just don't load any dynamic data. If we access the app with Opera by it's ip-address it loads well. Can't get the reason of this behavior.

Logs:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:42 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/ HTTP/1.1" 200 6222
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:42 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/res/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:42 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/res/image/main/flag.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:43 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/res/image/main/logo.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:43 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/res/image/main/footer-line.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:43 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/SomeApp/SomeApp.nocache.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:42 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/res/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:42 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 1021
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Nov/2012:00:17:43 +0400] "GET /SomeApp/SomeApp/D6F91CB485BE21BEBB0994EBE42E6F73.cache.html HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

Comment: And what have you done to obtain thoses logs? You have a Java tag on your question this probably means you have code something.

Comment: This logs are tomcat6 ones. Problem is with GWT-website which I'm developing. I don't had any troubles while it was accessed by IP-address. But when cyrillic domain name was bound to this IP, some problems started to occure. If website is still accessed by IP, there are no differences at all, everything works fine. But if we use cyrillic domain name to access website in Opera, everything looks like gwt-servlet.jar just isn't there. Other browsers (even Opera-mini) don't show such behavior.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to resolve this issue?